# Check if my ISP is blocking incoming connections on port 80 using traceroute

Tags: ip, http, traceroute

I am trying to expose a simple server over internet listening on port 80. I've configured iptables to accept incoming connections over http, so I don't if this means something but when I use traceroute to my own IP address I get:

```
190-90-90-90.dyn.dsl.cantv.net (190.90.90.90) ...
```

(Obviusly that's not my truly ip address but is an example). If I access to this address (including dyn.dsl.cantv.net) I get a right response using the browser in the computer but if a try to access from external using a mobile web browser I ever get

> too long time to response

This means that my ISP is blocking incoming connection from port 80 (http)?

I don't understand what is happening because I created another simple server but listening on 8443 using a self signed certificate (ssl) and going to https://190.90.90.90:8443 from external, using my mobile web browser I get a right response.

I don't know a good place to ask this question, but I think is maybe related with networking, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Did you run an http or https server on port 80? https uses port 443 by default.

Comment: The error on response I get using HTTP server listening on port (default for http).

Comment: The `https://190.90.90.90:8443` is just a reference of what works for me.

Answer (score 1):

"Ports" are related to TCP, UDP, or the lesser-used SCTP.  Traceroute has nothing to do with detected port 80.  The purpose of TraceRoute is to see which router drops packets.  (Traceroute is also rather useless for connection difficulties between devices within a single subnet.)

> This means that my ISP is blocking incoming connection from port 80 (http)?

Sounds like it, unless you can reach other sites at port 80.  Note, I'm not meaning to say that they are intentionally blocking it.  I'm just saying that the effect is essentially equivalent.  It might be a routing issue.

Contact your ISP.  If this is your phone company, then, having some experience, I would say that you may need to move beyond general "customer service" to speak to a "technical support" representative.

ISPs can generally either fix things, or help to identify that the problem is remote for the ISP (which is also helpful information).  In some cases they may be able to identify what company's behavior has a problem, and either let you know that or maybe even contact that company and help to get the problem resolved.

Comment: It could also be that the ISP is not blocking port 80, but bad firmware on the router is.  (Particularly where routers use port 80 for a web server...)

Comment: What are you referring as bad firmware on the router? @davidgo

Comment: I believe I have seen routers where you could not forward ports where the router had services bound to this ports. To me this is a bug/design flaw in the router firmware. If available, changing to dd-wrt can fix the problem.